# How to raise event in a separate class?

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have a class:

```
Class A
{
    public void EncodeMessage(object sender)
    {
        //Handle the Message received event
    }
}
```

Another class

```
Class B
{
     Message comMessage;

     public void RegisterForComMessageChange()
     {

     comMessage = ExtractComFromShcMessage();
     message.MessageReceived+= EncodeMessage; 
     //How to bind the message received event of this class to the event handler of Class A (i.e EncodeMessage)?

     }
}
```

How do I raise the register for an event in a separate class from that of the event handler?

Comment: What error are you getting?  And what is the exact type of `MessageReceived`?

Comment: @KirkWoll The error is that "EncodeMessage "does not exist in current context! This is because EncodeMessage exists in Class A. What I want is to be able to register to the event handler from Class B.                            MessageReceived is an event with following signature:.                                          
    public event MessageEventHandler<IMessage> MessageReceived;

Comment: Then you need an instance of class A.  `new A().EncodeMessage` would work, though is probably not what you want.  Presumably you need that instance passed in somewhere.